# datanode failed with org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException

Tags: hadoop

Recently, I installed Hadoop and formatted namenode . the namenode started well but  the  datanodes  started failed . here is  the datanode error log

```
  STARTUP_MSG:   build = git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r 3091053c59a62c82d82c9f778c48bde5ef0a89a1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2018-05-11T07:53Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_181
************************************************************/
2018-10-17 15:08:42,769 INFO  datanode.DataNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2018-10-17 15:08:43,665 INFO  checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker (ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:schedule(122)) - Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/hadoop/hdfs/data/
2018-10-17 15:08:43,682 ERROR datanode.DataNode (DataNode.java:secureMain(2692)) - Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Invalid value configured for dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated - 1. Value configured is >= to the number of configured volumes (1).
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2709)
2018-10-17 15:08:43,688 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2018-10-17 15:08:43,696 INFO  datanode.DataNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at hdp2.com/192.168.100.12
```

what  does  `dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated - 1`   means ?   What caused such a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check hdfs-site.xml. This property must be set to 0 or higher:

```
dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated
```

> The number of volumes that are allowed to fail before a datanode stops
>   offering service. By default any volume failure will cause a datanode
>   to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

when I try to solved this problem , I searched the  sourceCode

```
 final int volFailuresTolerated =
  conf.getInt(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_DATANODE_FAILED_VOLUMES_TOLERATED_KEY,
              DFSConfigKeys.DFS_DATANODE_FAILED_VOLUMES_TOLERATED_DEFAULT);

String[] dataDirs = conf.getTrimmedStrings(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_DATANODE_DATA_DIR_KEY);

int volsConfigured = (dataDirs == null) ? 0 : dataDirs.length;
int volsFailed = volsConfigured - storage.getNumStorageDirs();
this.validVolsRequired = volsConfigured - volFailuresTolerated;

if (volFailuresTolerated < 0 || volFailuresTolerated >= volsConfigured) {
  throw new DiskErrorException("Invalid volume failure "
      + " config value: " + volFailuresTolerated);
}
if (volsFailed > volFailuresTolerated) {
  throw new DiskErrorException("Too many failed volumes - "
      + "current valid volumes: " + storage.getNumStorageDirs() 
      + ", volumes configured: " + volsConfigured 
      + ", volumes failed: " + volsFailed
      + ", volume failures tolerated: " + volFailuresTolerated);
}
```

AS you see

> The number of volumes that are allowed to fail before a datanode stops
>   offering service. By default any volume failure will cause a datanode
>   to shutdown.

That is  the number of disk damage that datanode can tolerate.

In a Hadoop cluster, disk read-only or corruption often occurs. The datanode will use the folder configured under dfs.datanode.data.dir (used to store the block) at startup. If there are some values that cannot be used and the number configured above, the DataNode will fail to start.

In my hadoop environment, `fs.datanode.data.dir` is configured as 1 disks, so `dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated` is set to 1, which allows a disk to be bad. There is only one disk under the line, and the values of `volFailuresTolerated` and `volsConfigured` are both 1, so it will cause the code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following property form hdfs-site.xml file.

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:///C:/hadoop-3.3.0/data/datanode</value>
 </property>
```